# Create a new site collection with a subsite

Tags: 2013, site-collection

Hi in same web application how to create a new site collection based on existing subsite. 
I have below subsite:

http://webapp/sites/subsite1

I want to create a new site collection and import subsite1 under it:

http://webapp/sitecoll

Comment: Is this a one of, or is it intended as a general template for Site creation?

Answer (score 0):

You must export and import existed site to new blank site, if you want to move it to new site collection:

1. [Export the subsite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Export-SPWeb?view=sharepoint-ps) using the Export-SPWeb `http://webapp/sites/subsite1 -Path "subsite1_export.cmp"`
2. [Create a subsite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/New-SPWeb?view=sharepoint-ps) on the destination without template `New-SPWeb http://webapp2/sitecoll/subweb2`
3. [Import site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/import-spweb?view=sharepoint-ps) from exported file `Import-SPWeb http://webapp2/sitecoll/subweb2 -Path subsite1_export.cmp -IncludeUserSecurity -Overwrite`

Comment: I tried this but the imported site should have same template id like targe site